# Humming noise while turning right

Tags: dodge

I have a 2015 Dodge Dart sxt. Whenever I go anywhere from 25-like 60 mph, my car starts like a humming sound. But only when I start turning right like the road goes right. Not when I’m actually turning onto a new road. I hope someone kind of understands this and can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you looked at your tires (full circumference) to ensure they're in good shape?

Comment: Tyres or CV joint maybe?